# Can't serialize a list properly in .net mvc web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web service in .net but when i excute it with postman I get just a string json.

this my function :

```
        using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class ProduitController : ApiController
    {
        MyDataBaseContext dbcontext = new MyDataBaseContext();

        public IEnumerable<Produit> Get()
        {
            IList<Produit> produit = null;
            using (dbcontext)
            {
                produit = dbcontext.Produit.Include("Liste produit")
                      .Select(s => new Produit()
                      {
                          IdProduit=s.IdProduit,
                          NumeroSerie =s.NumeroSerie,
                          NomProduit=s.NomProduit,
                          Prix=s.Prix,
                          Quantite=s.Quantite,
                          IdModel=s.IdModel,
                          IdModelNavigation=s.IdModelNavigation

                      }).ToList<Produit>();
            }
            return produit;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            var produit = dbcontext.Produit.AsQueryable().
                     Where(i => i.IdProduit== id).ToList();
            if (produit == null)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Not found");

            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(produit);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

this is the Return string json that can't be serializable in my android application:

```
[
    "[{\"IdProduit\":1,\"NumeroSerie\":\"1234579657\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce BigKing\",\"Prix\":200.0,\"Quantite\":500,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}},{\"IdProduit\":2,\"NumeroSerie\":\"12345687\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce La Win\",\"Prix\":2000.0,\"Quantite\":60,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}},{\"IdProduit\":3,\"NumeroSerie\":\"124576328\",\"NomProduit\":\"Carte De Recharge 200DA\",\"Prix\":200.0,\"Quantite\":300,\"IdModel\":2,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":2,\"NomModel\":\"Carte De Recharge\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}}]"
]
```

expeted json in this return function must be lik this so this is a json array ofobjr=ect not an array of string for that my app does not serialze it properly;

```
[
   [
      {
         "IdProduit":1,
         "NumeroSerie":"1234579657",
         "NomProduit":"Puce BigKing",
         "Prix":200.0,
         "Quantite":500,
         "IdModel":1,
         "IdModelNavigation":{
            "IdModel":1,
            "NomModel":"Puces",
            "Produit":[

            ],
            "StockModel":[

            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "IdProduit":2,
         "NumeroSerie":"12345687",
         "NomProduit":"Puce La Win",
         "Prix":2000.0,
         "Quantite":60,
         "IdModel":1,
         "IdModelNavigation":{
            "IdModel":1,
            "NomModel":"Puces",
            "Produit":[

            ],
            "StockModel":[

            ]
         }
      }
     
   ]
]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong?

Comment: the json is not properly formated look at the json is just an array of one string

Comment: It is formatted properly, you have serialized tho whole list of  `Produit`'s into one string - list got formatted into json array. What have you expected?

Comment: one string inside array the properly json is be array of object

Comment: Your json string is json array of objects. What is wrong?

Comment: no it's a json array of one string

Comment: Your serialized result is fully correct based on your code. Can you please add desired output. And your result is json array of one string and this string contains json array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return type to `IEnumerable<Produit>`:

```
 public IEnumerable<Produit> Get()
    {
        using (dbcontext)
        {
            var produit = dbcontext.Produit.Include("Liste produit")
                  .Select(s => new Produit
                  {
                      IdProduit=s.IdProduit,
                      NumeroSerie =s.NumeroSerie,
                      NomProduit=s.NomProduit,
                      Prix=s.Prix,
                      Quantite=s.Quantite,
                      IdModel=s.IdModel,
                      IdModelNavigation=s.IdModelNavigation

                  }).ToList();
              return produit;
        }
    }
```

ASP will serialize the result for you, otherwise you will get your result serialized twice.

Currently you serialize your collection into `string` with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(produit)` and return `IEnumerable<String>` from your controller so you end up with collection of one `string` (via `yield return`) which is serialized ending up in the result in question.

**UPD**

To get desired output try this:

```
public IEnumerable<List<Produit>> Get()
{
    using (dbcontext)
    {
        var produit = dbcontext.Produit.Include("Liste produit")
              .Select(s => new Produit
              {
                  IdProduit=s.IdProduit,
                  NumeroSerie =s.NumeroSerie,
                  NomProduit=s.NomProduit,
                  Prix=s.Prix,
                  Quantite=s.Quantite,
                  IdModel=s.IdModel,
                  IdModelNavigation=s.IdModelNavigation

              }).ToList();
          return new [] { produit };
    }
}
```

Comment: @Medo this can't get you the same result =)

Comment: @Medo stop the application, clean and rebuild.

Comment: [
    "[{\"IdProduit\":1,\"NumeroSerie\":\"1234579657\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce BigKing\",\"Prix\":200.0,\"Quantite\":500,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}},{\"IdProduit\":2,\"NumeroSerie\":\"12345687\",\"NomProduit\":\"Puce La Win\",\"Prix\":2000.0,\"Quantite\":60,\"IdModel\":1,\"IdModelNavigation\":{\"IdModel\":1,\"NomModel\":\"Puces\",\"Produit\":[],\"StockModel\":[]}}}]"
]

Comment: @Medo please show your current code. And add desired output.

Comment: @Medo and it differs from one in my answer. If you have not changed your code to suggested how can you say that suggested returns the same result as yours?

Comment: the same result

Comment: @Medo please show your current version of the code.

Comment: @Medo this code works as expected on my machine. And it can't return the same result as you previous one.

Comment: share with me the hole class

Comment: this is not my way to implement a controller

Comment: @Medo the code in post is the code in the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217485/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-medo).